# Autocomplete an input by using a XML File with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i ve got this content of a XML File called customers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<searchName>Company ABC, ABC</searchName>
<stagingServer>server1.com</stagingServer>
<stagingDistributionID>KJDD43943FJJF</stagingDistributionID>
<liveServer>server2.com</liveServer>
<liveDistributionID>DJJDJDEJJD</liveDistributionID>

<operator>
    <name maintainer="1">Store New York</name>
    <opID>9832894984984</opID>
</operator>

<operator>
    <name>Store LA</name>
    <opID>983283289498</opID>
</operator>
```

```
<searchName>Mega Movie Company, MMC</searchName>
<stagingServer>movieserver.com</stagingServer>
<stagingDistributionID>9898JJJ9393</stagingDistributionID>
<liveServer>movieserver2.com</liveServer>
<liveDistributionID>JKDJJDJ33JKJKJ</liveDistributionID>

<operator>
    <name maintainer="1">Cool Movie Store</name>
    <opID>09093203232</opID>
</operator>

<operator>
    <name>Not So Cool Movie Store Texas</name>
    <opID>989832932983</opID>
</operator>
```

My goal is to have an input field where i can search for the "searchName" so iE Company ABC or just ABC.
And it should autocomplete the field, so if i type "Movie" it will show the "Mega Mobie Company,MMC".

More difficult is the next step, so if i select "Company ABC, ABC" and press iE "OK" , the function should submit all Data of this company. So i have alle servers and stores, the stores should be in an array.

i have no clue how to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get what you are trying to achieve is to parse the XML to JSON and work on the JSON object for all your filtering and submitting process.

Assuming what you provided to be the complete XML, the structure seems incorrect as it has multiple root elements and will not be parsed by standard XML to JSON parsers.

It would be better to pass the XML through a correctional process before trying to parse it to JSON. A better version of your XML would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable>
    <item>
        <searchName>Company ABC, ABC</searchName>
        <stagingServer>server1.com</stagingServer>
        <stagingDistributionID>KJDD43943FJJF</stagingDistributionID>
        <liveServer>server2.com</liveServer>
        <liveDistributionID>DJJDJDEJJD</liveDistributionID>
        <operator>
            <name maintainer="1">Store New York</name>
            <opID>9832894984984</opID>
        </operator>
        <operator>
            <name>Store LA</name>
            <opID>983283289498</opID>
        </operator>
    </item>
    <item>
        <searchName>Mega Movie Company, MMC</searchName>
        <stagingServer>movieserver.com</stagingServer>
        <stagingDistributionID>9898JJJ9393</stagingDistributionID>
        <liveServer>movieserver2.com</liveServer>
        <liveDistributionID>JKDJJDJ33JKJKJ</liveDistributionID>
        <operator>
            <name maintainer="1">Cool Movie Store</name>
            <opID>09093203232</opID>
        </operator>
        <operator>
            <name>Not So Cool Movie Store Texas</name>
            <opID>989832932983</opID>
        </operator>
    </item>
</searchable>
```

Here, `<searchable>` will serve as the single root element the XML needs and each "searchable" items are encapsulated as `<item>` for better grouping and management of information.

From here on out you are good to go. Use a simple XML to JSON library such as https://github.com/SummersRemote/xmlToJSON and create a JSON object from the XML schema.

Loop through all item in searchable like so

```
var json = xmlToJSON.parseString(xml);
for(i in json.searchable[0].item) {
    let item = json.searchable[0].item[i];
    // item can be accessed for all the data inside <item>
    // populate the array to be used for autocomplete using item (with i as index)
}
```

You can write the filtering process by splitting the `item.searchName[0]._text` and eliminating items that doesn't have a match.

When your autocomplete `on selected` or equivalent event fires, record the index of the captured item and access it's information like before.

```
let selectedItem = json.searchable[0].item[selectedIndex];
```

You can then populate a hidden field with information you you to send to a server before submitting it as a form or use XHR to POST data to your server.